# Max file size that Windows 64 and 32 bit can map using MapViewOfFile

Tags: c, windows, memory

I am working on a project that requires opening large files (hundreds of GB, possibly TBs). I need to make changes to these files so my plan is to map the file instead of creating another file, reading the original, making changes, and then saving.

This is what I have for this idea:

```
    hFile = CreateFile(filename, (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE), 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return;
    }

    hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (hFileMap == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return;
    }

    mapView = MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, amount);
    if (mapView == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hFileMap);
        return;
    }
```

After reading more into `MapViewOfFile` it seems that this is mapped in the programs virtual address space. For a 64 bit machine I am reading the max size is 2^64 bytes (16 exabytes). And for 32 bit it is 2GB.

If the 64 bit number is correct, I wouldn't need to do any sort of chunking of the file and creating multiple views. But on 32 bit if I come across a file that is large (>2GB) I would need to chunk it?

Is the amount also limited on RAM or HDD space?

Comment: Reasonably speaking you'll have to chunk the file either way because unless you have enough memory to back that file you're going to run into issues. You'd probably also want to use [`MapViewOfFile3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile3) so you can specify quite a bit of how you're mapping, such as using large pages for efficiency. But the biggest obstacles you're likely to get is physical ram not being there.

Comment: So I need to find a sweet spot for the chunk size? I was thinking something like 500mb since this is going to be ran on different machines and I don't know the hardware configuration.

Comment: Up to you, you could probably get away with a gig or two if you can basically toss out 32bit. Personally the number of configurations with less than 8GB of physical ram is getting smaller by the day IME. But it's worth setting minimum system requirements. At the same time you don't want to tell your customers they have to close chrome to run your program. You could always size dynamically too. But using things like Large pages will help with efficiency of access as well.

Comment: I can do some hardware enumeration I suppose and calculate the size based on that. I also see that ```MapViewOfFile3``` has Windows 10 v1803 as the minimum supported client which may be an issue.

Comment: Do you have clients running on ESB or unsupported versions of windows? Otherwise that should be an out of support version.  Worst case you fall back to [`MapViewOfFile2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile2) which is supported on 1703 which is the ESB version

Comment: I am not sure what ESB is.

Comment: Enterprise Servicing branch or Long Term Servicing branch. Basically a version of windows 10 that MS commits to patching for at least 5 years.

Answer (score 3):

The effective limit on 32-bit is much smaller than 2GB. How small is impossible to say. The problem is that the address space is shared with other memory allocations, special system pages and other loaded .DLLs.

For example, if your application uses the open/save common dialogs then this will load COM and whatever 3rd-party shell extensions you might have installed (NSEs, icon overlays, context menus etc) and these .DLLs might stay loaded for a while (some never unload) causing your address space to become fragmented and leaving no free large continuous range of usable addresses.

A way to mitigate this is to call `VirtualAlloc` early in your program to reserve a large range, 500-1000MB perhaps. Release the reserved range just before you map the file.

If your files are always > 1GB and you want to support 32-bit then you must implement an alternative routine that maps in smaller chunks. For 64-bit, the address space is so large that you should have no issues with lack of free addresses.

Mapping files into memory is not free, it will require some free RAM for the page tables. This is probably architecture specific.

Comment: For 64 bit I would still be limited on RAM correct? If I have a 100GB file and only 8GB of ram is this going to be an issue? I could probably get away with this running on 32 bit so would be more interested in knowing at what file size would I need to start chunking if the PC had 4GB or 8GB of RAM.

Comment: I don't know the limits off the top of my head but I would assume 8GB is more than enough to map a 100GB file. The entire file is never in RAM at the same time (unless you lock the pages), the kernel will deal with swapping pages in and out.

Comment: Removed my comments suggesting large pages... there are some serious issues with that not the least of which is they are disabled by default. This means that @xx9000 should seriously consider windowing due to overhead otherwise from page tables.

Comment: I am not familiar with windowing.

Comment: @xx9000 windowing is just changing the part of the file visible in the memory map. It's the same as chunking in effect.